# Wok seasoning.. Again

Tags: seasoning-pans, wok, carbon-steel

Hi so after removing old seasoning on my wok with vinegar baking powder and a lot of scrubbing, i tried to season it again. But i could not get any good results ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekj0K.jpg )
As you can see the oil did not act as a layer but like some drops dripping.. I am sure i didnt use too much (it was really a thin layer) but once starting to burn, the oil grouped in these weird lines. Could that be the patterns of my towel showing off? I am really confused... I am doing it over the gas stove because i dont have any oven. If anyone can help it is really annoying because its the only pan i have right now and the small seasoning i made still peeled when cooking... Thanks!!

Comment: Rule #1 - don't burn the oil. Pan too hot.

Answer (score 1):

Just to expound upon what @Tetsujin wrote above, if you burned the oil start again. And by start again, I mean scrub off the burnt residual oils and go from there

If you don't have an oven you will need to be extra careful. The beauty of an oven is you can set the temperature more easily. I would recommend you try and find a place to season it that has an oven. This will help you avoid this issue in the future.

Comment: Well by burn i meant polymerise or something like that, becoming brown then black with smoke and all, cause i used pretty low flame. I seasoned my pan before and it did the same reaction, but as a layer not as "stripes" like this, and the seasoning was effective (i just forgot soup inside for a day so it went off). I just don't understand why it does not stay as a layer..

Comment: If there's too much oil it will keep dribbling towards the centre of the pan. So a) use less oil, b) use a paper towel & keep spreading it around & c) you burned it so you'll have to start over.

Comment: @Tetsujin glad to see we are on the same page! Good luck Nat!